# aspnet core 1.0 rc2 EntityFramework 6

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

I am looking to start a project and I would like to use EF6 with my aspnet core 1.0 rc2 project. The EF6 project is a .net46 project. In trying this out, I keep getting errors in my project.json saying something about the projects are not compatible (net46 and netcore 1.0 or so). I changed the settings in my project.json and added the full clr .net46 to get to these errors. The manual's explanation about rc2 specific instructions doesn't go far enough for me So I was hoping if anyone has been able to get this scenario working and if they would share what they know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **only** full dotnet framework in your `project.json` like this:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {}
   }
```

In this case every classic dotnet library should work.
Hope it helps.

Comment: your answer is very helpful, as i found the same thing to be true. Was concerned about the version number being 451 but was put straight that 451 could be 46 or 461. So thanks